# Problem calculating possibility of birthday paradox

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday

I am working on the problem of birthday paradox:

> How many people do you need to reach 50% chance of at least one pair with matching birthday?

When I first heard the problem I verified the answer 23 by subtracting possibility of 23 people with different birthdays from 1.

$$ 1 - \frac{{}_{365} \mathrm{P}_{23}}{365^{23}} $$

I assumed this should work as people are distinguishable objects and 23 people have ${}_{365} \mathrm{P}_{23}$ permutations of not matching birthdays.

And yet according to [scientific american article](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/bring-science-home-probability-birthday-paradox/) one should calculate

$$ 1 - \left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{\sum_{ i = 1 }^{22} i}$$

because we make $\sum_{ i = 1 }^{22} i$ comparisons and two people have $\frac{364}{365}$ chance of not matching birthday.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What problem are you working on? what do you mean by "verified the answer 23"?

Comment: Oh sorry I thought birthday paradox was a proper noun not a generic class of problems. I was working on original(?) wording : How many people do you need to reach 50% chance of at least one pair with matching birthday.

Comment: I could somehow guess the problem, but probably not able to guess that you are working on 50% chance. I'll edit your question.

Comment: The article appears to be wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method is exact. The article's method is an [approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#A_simple_exponentiation). What you are looking for is the [Reverse Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Reverse_problem), which has a nice approximation.

Comment: Thanks! Wording of birthday paradox was more intricate than I expected it to be. My understanding of combinatorics is really elementary and I'm really uncomfortable with approximations. So when one assumes "two people sharing the same birthday" as independent events, does it mean to consider people as indistinguishable objects by ignoring past comparisons?

Comment: The birthdays themselves are independent events. Two people sharing the same birthday is one singular event. The exact answer considers people only as birthdays, and the idea behind it looks more like someone filling up a calendar with birthdays than actual comparisons between two people. The part after the "$1-$" in the first formula is the probability that two people do not share the same birthday.